# HTML5 - Way: FB is not defined

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

thats my Code - it's the new HTML5-Way to include the JS-FB-Api:

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

That's working good.. for Like-Buttons and somethings else. But if I want to use FB.Event.subscribe..:

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
            $('#head h1 a').text('liked');
        });
        $('#head h1 a').text('loaded');
    }
```

...Firebug told me that FB is not defined. But window.fbAsyncInit was fired successfully.. so where is the problem?

Thanks for ur answers and sorry for my bad English!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, I could use it with Firefox, although FireBug was pointing out there is some error.
I couldn't use it with Chrome, and its console said that FB is not defined.
Then I tried it like this, and it works:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
/* FB Likes */
FB.Event.subscribe("edge.create",function(response){
    $.ajax({
        /* bla bla */
    });
});
FB.Event.subscribe("edge.remove",function(response){
    $.ajax({
        /* bla bla */
    });
});
};
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/bs_BA/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=MY-APP-ID";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

And this works, no errors like FB.init already called or anything like it :)

Answer (score 0):

I am using HTML5 based Facebook integration on a site that also uses jQuery.

My code slightly differs from yours and maybe the differences matter:

```
if ($("#fb-root").length>0) {  
  // no window.fbAsyncInit w/o <div id="fb-root" /> being present in DOM

  // call FB.init() first
  FB.init(...); // you should pass the arguments you need for this

  // call other stuff after FB.init()
  FB.event.subscribe(...); // you should pass the arguments you need for this
}
```

Comment: So I have to use FB.init with my FB-App-ID? I thought that's enough when I typed in my App-ID in the line:
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

Comment: I don't really know if you *have to* do this, but at least rule this out as a non-solution.